# Inputbox desde php y oracle

Tags: php, oracle, entrada

Quiero mostrar como opciones el resultado de esta consulta para posteriormente utilizarlas.

```
$qsucursal = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT Id_Sucursal, Sucursal FROM TblSucursales;'); //Consulta
oci_execute($qsucursal);//Ejecutando consulta
```

Recorro los resultados y los coloco dentro de un input, pero no funciona.

```
while(($fila= oci_fetch_array($qsucursal, OCI_BOTH)) != false)
        { 
           echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$fila["Id_Sucursal"].'" value="'.$fila["Sucursal"]'">';
        }
```

Comment: El mensaje de error que presenta nos ayudaría a verificar cual es el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente, es necesario que mantengas controlado en todo momento el flujo del programa, indicando mensajes pertinentes que indiquen lo que está pasando.

En ese control, debes verificar:

- Que la conexión funciona
- Que la consulta arroja datos
- Si arroja datos leerla
- Cerrar recursos

En cuanto a la lectura de datos, podrías estar teniendo problemas con la mezcla de comillas simples `'` y comillas dobles `"`.

Para evitar esa confusión, es mejor construir una variable dentro del bucle:

```
$html="";
while(($fila= oci_fetch_array($qsucursal, OCI_BOTH)) != false)
        { 

           $id_sucursal=$row["Id_Sucursal"];
           $sucursal=$row["Sucursal"];
           $html.="<input type='checkbox' name='$id_sucursal' value='$sucursal'>";

        }

//Imprimes la variable que se creó 
echo $html;
```